# Assistance with PayPal Adaptive Payments - IOS and Android development

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, braintree

I'm currently developing a mobile application which will list businesses in a marketplace type format i.e. individual business listings, allowing users to purchase smalls items through our application. 
Ideally each individual end user will be able to select their desired payment method such as PayPal, Mastercard or visa during sign up; however, we would also like to provide the option to change their desired payment option at a later stage.
The payment details saved by the end user will be stored and then delegated to the businesses at the end of the month etc.
Payment to the businesses will be made at end of month less our fees/subscription.

We conducted research and decided PayPal Adaptive payments to be the ideal option for chained payments to each business; based on the review of Braintree, Stripe and PayPal. Braintree was our next option however they don't offer their marketplace solution to customers outside of the US.
We have attempted to contact PayPal Developer support on numerous occasions, though have not had much luck in confirming what is required for a complete end to end solution based on our needs.

Our questions for the community are, will PayPal adaptive payments allow for the following:

- Provide our end users (purchasing user) the option to choose between PayPal and other credit card options such as Mastercard, Visa, ApplePay
- Store user payment details and allow for future updating of payment option
- Allow Scan card API so a user scans their credit card using native IOS or Android camera?
- Allow for top up type functionality so a user can add funds and top up when funds are low?

Our developer has not worked with the PayPal Adaptive solution, however, believe we cannot implement the above requirements with the Adaptive payment option.

The community we need your HELP as we are currently at a roadblock in the development of the payment solution therefore if anyone has implemented a similar mobile solution your advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I hope my questions are clear, though please feel free to request additional information.

Regards,
Wayne

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Adaptive Payments is in a limited release.  See [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) Developer Doc on the PayPal Developer website.  Although they will continue to support Adaptive Payments for existing users, they will not likely accept new applications unless there is a special circumstance.

May I suggest looking into the PayPal owned company [Braintree Marketplace](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview)?

Comment: Link broken *-->* [Braintree v.zero Marketplace](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplace/)

Comment: Right you are. PayPal took down their documentation page for Braintree Marketplace.  I updated the link, thanks for noticing!